# Finding "nice" solution for under-determined system with constraint?

Tags: equation-solving, symbolic, parametric-functions, constraint

Consider the following equation:

```
0 == 32 + 8 a^2 (2 + b) + 4 a (2 + b) (6 + b) - b (-4 (8 + U1 + U2 - W1) + b (-8 + (-2 + U1) U1 - 2 U2 + W1^2 + 2 W2) + 2 (U2^2 + W2^2))
```

We have two variables `U2` and `W2` available to us, which we can fix in order to solve this equation. However, there are some constraints:

> `U2` may not contain `W1`, and `W2` may not contain `U1`.

I would like to find classes of solutions in variables `{U2,W2}` satisfying these constraints, so that I can single out some specific "nice" looking solution (i.e. no square roots, as short as possible) to use. Any suggestions on how to do this in *Mathematica*?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, you wish to obtain a parameterized solution `{U2[U1], W2[W1]}` from the equation in the question, so that you can vary that parameter to obtain a "nice" solution.  One approach is as follows.  Define

```
exp = 32 + 8 a^2 (2 + b) + 4 a (2 + b) (6 + b) - b (-4 (8 + U1 - W1 + U2[U1]) + 
    b (-8 + (-2 + U1) U1 + W1^2 - 2 U2[U1] + 2 W2[W1]) + 2 (U2[U1]^2 + W2[W1]^2))
```

and split `exp` into an expression dependent only on `U1` and another dependent only on `W1`.

```
su = Flatten@DSolve[D[exp, U1] == 0, U2[U1], U1] /. C[1] -> cu
(* {U2[U1] -> 1/2 (2 + b - Sqrt[4 + 4 b + b^2 - 4 cu + 8 U1 + 4 b U1 - 2 b U1^2]),
    U2[U1] -> 1/2 (2 + b + Sqrt[4 + 4 b + b^2 - 4 cu + 8 U1 + 4 b U1 - 2 b U1^2])} *)

sw = Flatten@DSolve[D[exp, W1] == 0, W2[W1], W1] /. C[1] -> cw
(* {W2[W1] -> 1/2 (-b - Sqrt[b^2 + 4 cw - 8 W1 - 2 b W1^2]), 
    W2[W1] -> 1/2 (-b + Sqrt[b^2 + 4 cw - 8 W1 - 2 b W1^2])} *)
```

`{U2[U1], W2[W1]}` now are parameterized in terms of constants `{cu, cw}`.  However, `exp == 0` still is to be satisfied.  Do so by

```
FullSimplify[exp /. {su[[1]], sw[[1]]}]
(* 2 (16 + 4 a^2 (2 + b) + 2 a (2 + b) (6 + b) + b (16 + 4 b + cu - cw)) *)
```

(`FullSimplify[exp /. {su[[2]], sw[[2]]}]` gives the same result.)

```
Flatten@Solve[(% /. cu - cw -> c) == 0, c]
(* {c -> -((2 (8 + 12 a + 4 a^2 + 8 b + 8 a b + 2 a^2 b + 2 b^2 + a b^2))/b)} *)
```

Thus, with `cu - cw` now known, `{U2[U1], W2[W1]}` is parameterized in terms of a single constant, say `cu + cw`, which can be varied to obtain the "nice" solution.

Comment: Unfortunately, the constant `cu+cw` is not sufficient to kill off the square root in both `U2[U1]` and `W2[W1]`, but I might be able to tweak my expression to get an extra unfixed constant in to do that.